# Python Scapy / operator, | pipe in types

Tags: python, scapy

With scapy we can to this :

```
p = Ether() / IP()
```

What kind of operation does '/' really do ? What kind of object does it return ?
If I type p in a python interpreter it returns this

```
<Ether  ... | IP ...>
```

What does '|' mean in this case ?

I was trying to change the field dst of IP after creating p without recreating the object entirely, but I didn't manage to do it as I don't know what kind of object I am facing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The div `/` operator is used in Scapy to [stack layers](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#stacking-layers):

> The / operator has been used as a composition operator between two
>   layers. When doing so, the lower layer can have one or more of its
>   defaults fields overloaded according to the upper layer.

The `|` in your printing output is just a text separator to help you distinguish between stacked layers.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen the operator in a socket library in C++. Is this scapy's own feature, or is it available more generally in python ? Is this used for anything else than sockets for instance ?

Comment: @x4rkz Scapy made it unique to choose to overide the div operaotr, other libraries prefer to override `|` operator.

Comment: Okay, but I mean the general layer feature, is it specific to scapy ? Did scapy implemented a totally new feature, or does there exist a more primitive layer feature in python which scapy improved ?

Comment: In Python the behavior of all operators can be customized per class. Many libraries and framework make use of this to offer convenient ways to combine objects.

Comment: new link to stacking layers - https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#stacking-layers

Comment: Can you please explain more, simpler ? I couldn't understand. What do you mean by "the lower layer can have one or more of its defaults fields overloaded according to the upper layer." ? @Assem